# My Jquery function stops working after the filter of my webshop has been used. Ajax Loadings

Tags: jquery

Dear Stackoverflow Members,

I am using this code:

```
     if($(window).width() > 1549 && $('.ShowProductCategoryHolder').length > 0) {

       $('#ProductContainer .martoni-product-item:nth-of-type(12n+0)').after('<html>Something</html>');
        }  else if ($(window).width() > 1199 && $(window).width() < 1550 && $('.ShowProductCategoryHolder').length > 0) {
            $('#ProductContainer .martoni-product-item:nth-of-type(9n+0)').after('<html>Something</html>');
        } else if ($(window).width() > 767 && $(window).width() < 1200 && $('.ShowProductCategoryHolder').length > 0) {
            $('#ProductContainer .martoni-product-item:nth-of-type(9n+0)').after('<html>Something</html>');
        } 

});

});
```

This Code is fully operational on the website. And ensures that certain Unique selling points on our webshop are displayed to a certain number of products. However, when there are filters used on the website. Then the Jquery stops working. How do I rewrite these codes, or what should I add to ensure that they continue to work after an Ajax Loading. I used to use live () before. But have no idea how to process that in this code.

Comment: From your paragraph, it sounds like your question is related to event handlers and event delegation, however your code is completely unrelated. If you were using `$("#myElement").live("click", function() {...})`, try `$(document).on("click", "#myElement", function() { ... });` instead. That being said, **[I have a hunch that this question is a duplicate...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)**.

Comment: Let me reformulate. I use the code on top of this. To call a jquery function that implements <html> After a certain amount of products in my webshop. When I use the filter it doesn't work. I just need a solution to make sure that this code is always active. Even though the filter has triggered ajax loading.

Comment: Thus, once I select the filter. The Jquery code stops working.

Comment: To make it even more clear. The Jquery code pasted above is only active once the page loads. Whenever someone will use the filter on my webshop to search for specific products the Jquery code isn't reactivated. It just stops working. I have the feeling it as something to do with Ajax being activated by the filters.

Comment: AJAX doesn't refresh the page... if this is just running when your page loads then it won't run again when you run an AJAX method.

Comment: And how can I change this code to make sure that it keeps running after an AJAX method is used.

Comment: Make it a function, and put that function in the callback method of your AJAX. If you're using `$.ajax`, there's a `success` property that will run after a successful call.